# how to change a list according to screen size(less than 500px)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my user is showing 4 educational titles. I want it to only show 1 on mobile screen(less than 500px); How can I Accomplish this in react? below is the code and how it looks on a normal wide screen resolution and how Id like it to look

```
return (
        <div className="educations-section">
            {user.educations.map(
                (educationRecord) => (
                    <div key={educationRecord._id}>{educationRecord.degree}</div>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could use CSS for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some conditioned rendering

```js
let show1 = window.innerWidth <= 500;
return (
        <div className="educations-section">
            { Show1 && <div key={user.educations[0]._id}>{user.educations[0].degree}</div>}
            { !Show1 && user.educations.map(
                (educationRecord) => (
                    <div key={educationRecord._id}>{educationRecord.degree}</div>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: let me know if this works, if it does then please dont forget to mark this as the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and I am sorry if it took me this long to respond. I talked to my supervisor and it turns out that he did not want to hide anything, including the education. I left it as is but your effort were gladly appreciated, Thank you.